# Unity3D - Emission value parameter not showing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a material using Emission, after ticking the option I can select the color. In the official [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterEmission.html), and in a tutorial I'm trying to follow, a new field appears controlling the amount of emission you'd like to have.

On my screen, this field doesn't appear :
[image: Emission]

While in the documentation, in the "red circle" on the above screenshot, you can see this field :
[image: Doc]

Am I missing something here, or is it just a bug ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out the solution, I guess it changed during a recent update.

The intensity slider isn't in the inspector anymore, but with the color picker :

[image]